# Improving chances of entering a Theoretical Physics program in the US

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, physics

I am a current undergraduate student majoring in Physics in a US institution. I am thinking of doing my PhD in Theoretical Physics also in a US institution. I think I know the basic things I should do to have a strong application:

- Have a very good GRE score
- Do some research in my undergrad institution (some theory research exposure would be good)
- Strong letters of recommendation
- Take advanced courses in Physics and Math in my school.

I am currently in my senior year, is there any extra advice you might have for improving my chances of entering a Theoretical Physics PhD program? Either during my senior year or when I apply ? ( I am planning to apply next year)

Comment: Take advanced courses *and do well in them*.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to do a PhD in theoretical physics? And why do you think that you'd be able to successfully complete a PhD in theoretical physics? Theoretical physics is hard. And to obtain a PhD in theoretical physics you need to contribute to its development. I'm not a physicist so I don't speak from experience. But I've read some accounts by theoretical physicists and a drop out of how grueling it can be. If you want to improve your chances, then know what you're getting yourself into and why you want it and why you might succeed. Be honest with yourself.